# Fixing bugs in a github project SwiftChart

Tags: ios, swift, github, plot

I'm trying to track down the errors in this github project.

https://github.com/gpbl/SwiftChart

The owner doesn't seem to answer any questions or respond.

I can't get this example to run:

```
// Create a new series specifying x and y values
let data = [(x: 0, y: 0), (x: 0.5, y: 3.1), (x: 1.2, y: 2), (x: 2.1, y: -4.2), (x: 2.6, y: 1.1)]
let series = new ChartSeries(data)
chart.addSerie(series)
```

Xcode gives this error in regards to the data

```
ViewController.swift:41:31: '(Double, Double)' is not identical to 'Float'
```

in the main file Chart.swift, there is this section of code

```
var labels: [Float]
if xLabels == nil {
  // Use labels from the first series
  labels = series[0].data.map( { (point: ChartPoint) -> Float in
    return point.x } )
}
else {
  labels = xLabels!
}
```

I'm not quite sure how to deal with the map .

Comment: Your question is not clear. What does the code in `Chart.swift` has to do with your exception?

Comment: what is not clear?  the data is an array of [(Double, Double)] the subroutine is expecting [Float].  Chart.swift is the file where that section of code is located for people who want to look at the complete code.

Comment: I think you are wrong. The exception comes from the constructor of ChartSeries. But there is not enough information in your question.

Comment: the questions is how to fix this repo so it will accept (x,y).  the data is given here https://github.com/gpbl/SwiftChart  in the Chart.swift file  `Represent the x- and the y-axis values for each point in a chart series.
*/
typealias ChartPoint = (x: Float, y: Float)`

Comment: Check my fork for one possible fix, or feel free to clone it.  I'll add the init I created in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are typos in the realm.  It should read

```
let data = [(x: 0, y: 0), (x: 0.5, y: 3.1), (x: 1.2, y: 2), (x: 2.1, y: -4.2), (x: 2.6, y: 1.1)]
let series = ChartSeries(data)
chart.addSeries(series)
```

That being said, Swift by default infers 0.5 to be a Double, and his default init is looking for x and y to be of type Float.

I forked the repository, and added an init that will convert the doubles to float.  This could obviously cause an issue if the double is too big, but for the small numbers it likely won't be an issue.  I also added the example in question to the actual project.  My fork is [here](https://github.com/pope13/SwiftChart).

I'll send a pull request if the owner wants to accept the changes.  Otherwise, if I have time I may refactor it to all be Double and get rid of the extra init.

I added the following init in ChartSeries.swift, this prevents you from always having to define your array as it convert the array of Double value tuples to Floats.

```
init(data: Array<(x: Double, y: Double)>) {
    self.data = data.map ({ (Float($0.x), Float($0.y))})
}
```

Comment: ok thanks.  i haven't updated to latest swift yet.  i tried you solution but got error `/ViewController.swift:42:37: 'Double' is not identical to 'Float'`  but i did this `let data: [(x: Float,y: Float)] = [(0, 0), (0.5, 3.1), (1.2, 2), ( 2.1,  -4.2),  (2.6, 1.1)] let series3 = ChartSeries(data: data)` and it worked.